# Dataframe list to array comma delimited by value and semicolon delimited by line

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, join, split

Updated question and solution added.

I am trying to convert a dataframe back to array. I started with CSV file containing the the following

```
1.0,2.0,1.0,4.0;2.0,3.0,1.0,2.0;1.0,4.0,6.0,3.0
```

I open and split with

```
with open('PV.csv','r') as f:
    array = [l.split(",") for l in f.readline().split(";") if l]
```

I then convert to dataframe and output to CSV with the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame(array).replace(regex = '\n', value = '')
df.to_csv('OUT.csv', index=False, header=None)
```

which gives this if I open the CSV with Notepad.

```
1.0 2.0 1.0 4.0
2.0 3.0 1.0 2.0
1.0 4.0 6.0 3.0
```

Full code is

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

# Read from CSV
with open('IN.csv', 'r') as f:
      array = [l.split(",") for l in f.readline().split(";") if l]
f.close()
# Convert to Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(array).replace(regex = '\n', value = '')
# Save as CSV
df.to_csv('OUT.csv', index=False, header=None)
array = ';'.join(','.join(a) for a in array)
print(array)

with open('OUT.csv', 'w') as f:
      writer = csv.writer(f)
      writer.writerow(array)
```

This now produces the correct output when I print to screen

```
1.0,2.0,1.0,4.0;2.0,3.0,1.0,2.0;1.0,4.0,6.0,3.0
```

but does produces this when I save as CSV

```
1,.,0,",",2,.,0,",",1,.,0,",",4,.,0,;,2,.,0,",",3,.,0,",",1,.,0,",",2,.,0,;,1,.,0,",",4,.,0,",",6,.,0,",",3,.,0,"
"
```

I worked it out if anyone has the same issue. Thanks for those that helped.

```
import csv

# Read from CSV
with open('IN.csv', 'r') as f:
      array = [l.split(",") for l in f.readline().split(";") if l]
# Rejoin
array = ';'.join(','.join(a) for a in array)
# Output to CSV
with open('OUT.csv', 'w') as f:
      f.writelines(array)
```

Comment: When you wrote "which gives", that's not the actual output, right? Isn't `array` a list of lists? Is your question how to convert that list of lists back to the original string returned by `f.readline()`?

Comment: @Joe Exactly my question. I tried to use 'join' but all I get is a line of values separated by a comma. I can't get the semicolon for the change in record.

Comment: Does `';'.join(','.join(a) for a in array)` work?

Comment: @Joe Not exactly. I have confused myself with calling is an array and trying to simplify the question. The CSV file has headers which I had deleted when I took the snip above. The code is this

'with open('PV.csv', 'r') as infile, open('PVout.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
      reader = csv.reader(infile)
      next(reader, None) #remove the header
      for row in reader: #this is just to screen print while I debug
            print(row)'
I want write back to the outfile as per the original format.

Comment: When you say "I want write back to the outfile as per the original format", is that `1.0,2.0,1.0,4.0;2.0,3.0,1.0,2.0;1.0,4.0,6.0,3.0`?  If not, you should edit your post to show exactly what output you'd like to achieve.

Comment: You can also try the csv module’s writer method and set the delimiter=‘,’ and lineterminator=‘;’: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters.